# c11 _Generic adding types

Tags: c, generics, overloading, c11

How do you add extra types to c11 _Generic Functions?

Do you have to #undef/re-#define it?(if so would the following work) or is there a nicer way?

```
#define to_str(X) _Generic((X), \
    long double: ld_str, \
    double: d_str, \
    float: f_str, \
    )(X)

#undef to_str

#define to_str(X) _Generic((X), \
    long double: ld_str, \
    double: d_str, \
    float: f_str, \
    int: i_str, \
    )(X)
```

Answer (score 8):

I am not sure that I understand your question completely. You mean that you have a type generic macro that is given by some library and you want to amend it with a new type of your own?

What you always could do is to give it another name and use the default case to obtain the provided behavior:

```
#define to_str2(X) _Generic((X), default: to_str(X), int: i_str(X))
```

*Edit*:

This will not work perfectly because you'd have to put the function argument evaluation inside the `_Generic`. This means in particular that the type of `X` has to be compatible with all branches of the nested generic expressions.

It would be easier if the library in question had a macro that would just return the function itself, without the `(X)`, say `to_strGen`, and that never would evaluate `X`. Then you could do

```
#define to_str2Gen(X) _Generic((X), default: to_strGen(X), int: i_str)
#define to_str2(X) to_str2Gen(X)(X)
```

Comment: Caution: if the original macro doesn’t define a `default` selection, then wrapping won’t work.  See the thread [Nested _Generic selections](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.lang.c/1RQvT2a5DF0/discussion) on comp.lang.c.

Comment: @J.C.Salomon, the lack of a `default` isn't the problem, I think, but the compability of `X` with all branches of the type generic expression is, I think. See my edit.

Answer (score 3):

If it's your code, you would have to `#undef` it and re`#define` it, yes.  There's no way to extend a type-generic expression (AFAIK).

If it's not your code I'd introduce a second expression with the extension like Jens suggested.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is:

```
#define to_str(X) _Generic((X), \
    long double: ld_str, \
    double: d_str, \
    float: f_str \
    EXTRA_TYPES \
    )(X)

#define EXTRA_TYPES \
,int: i_str, \
char: c_str
```

notice how the comma is part of the `EXTRA_TYPES` and not the `to_str` macro. This is to make `to_str` work even if `EXTRA_TYPES` was empty.

Now all you have to do is define `EXTRA_TYPES` with the types you need.